# HTML: attribute double quotes not working-

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!-- button line has  the error message "tag start  is not closed"single quotes fixes the problem,which is confusing since double quotes is supposed to work on everything -->

<body>

  <h2> what can javascript do?</h2>

  <p id="demo">javascript can hide html elemnts.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display=" none "">click me!</button>

</body>
```

Comment: 'none' vs "none"   the single quotes works fine but the double quotes doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help in clearing this up

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes; Doube quotes will end the string which are you passing to the onclick attribute, leading to a systax error when the string is parsed as javascript. It will be interpreted as:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display="
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<!-- button line has  the error message "tag start  is not closed"single quotes fixes the problem,which is confusing since double quotes is supposed to work on everything -->

<body>

<h2> what can javascript do?</h2>

<p id="demo">javascript can hide html elemnts.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none'">click me!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The onclick property is all lower-case, and accepts a function, not a string and as you are using Double quotes, you should use single quote in the other place.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this snippet ..

**Using single quotes**

```
 onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.display="none"'
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<!-- button line has  the error message "tag start  is not closed"single quotes fixes the problem,which is confusing since double quotes is supposed to work on everything -->

<body>

<h2> what can javascript do?</h2>

<p id="demo">javascript can hide html elemnts.</p>

<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.display="none"'>click me!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

**Using double quotes**

```
 onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none'"
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<!-- button line has  the error message "tag start  is not closed"single quotes fixes the problem,which is confusing since double quotes is supposed to work on everything -->

<body>

<h2> what can javascript do?</h2>

<p id="demo">javascript can hide html elemnts.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none'">click me!</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better for code readability and to handle such cases, if you create a function that will be invoked when clicked on a button would be a better option.

```js
function onclickhandle(){
  console.log("hidden")
  document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none';
}
```

```html
<!-- button line has  the error message "tag start  is not closed"single quotes fixes the problem,which is confusing since double quotes is supposed to work on everything -->


<h2> what can javascript do?</h2>

<p id="demo">javascript can hide html elemnts.</p>

<button type="button"onclick="onclickhandle()">click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
onCLick="document.querySelector('#demo').style.display='none'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single quote within a double quote  as following :

```
onclick=" document.getElementById('demo').style.display='none' "
```